# Compare two variables in C# Visual Studio using DataTable.Compute() method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string output = (dt.Compute("3 > 2", String.Empty)).ToString();
MessageBox.Show("Output is " + output);
```

if I compare 3 > 2, it gives me True but I want to achieve similar functionality

using variables such as:

string output = (dt.Compute("a > b", String.Empty)).ToString();

how can I add my variables to the table to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute needs a string expression to work, you can provide the expression with interpolating the values from your variables as in

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
string output = (dt.Compute($"{a} > {b}", String.Empty)).ToString();
```

However, as [@JohnG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842716/johng) pointed in a comment below, a question needs to be asked here. Why do you need this? You can get the same result with probably a better performance using simple lines of code like

```
string output = "false";
if(a > b)
    output = "true";
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I have to ask, why would introducing the data tables `Compute` function have anything to do with the external values? It just seems unnecessary to me to introduce the data tables compute function for this when `var result = a > b ? "true" : "false";` will accomplish the same thing. What am I missing here?